# Facing Issues in VPN

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

My code was working correctly today i have open project in android studio it giving me errors

I have not made any changes in code but one thing is that i have updated my android studio to latest version

**Here is the build error**

```
> FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform openvpn-aar-0.18.2.jar (com.github.AnchorFree.hydra-vpn-android:openvpn-aar:0.18.2) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not find openvpn-aar-0.18.2.jar (com.github.AnchorFree.hydra-vpn-android:openvpn-aar:0.18.2).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://jitpack.io/com/github/AnchorFree/hydra-vpn-android/openvpn-aar/0.18.2/openvpn-aar-0.18.2.jar

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

**Module level build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
ext {
    androidSupportLibraryVersion = "28.0.0"
}
android {
    signingConfigs {
        sining {
            storeFile file('E:\\arfatechnology.jks')
            storePassword 'arfatechnology'
            keyPassword 'arfatechnology'
            keyAlias 'arfatechnology'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.maxprovpn.fast.vpn.fastvpn"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 6
        versionName "4.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_HOST", "\"https://backend.northghost.com\""
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_CARRIER_ID", "\"1212_demotest\""
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_OAUTH_METHOD", "\"anonymous\""

        buildConfigField "String", "SHARED_PREFS", "\"NORTHGHOST_SHAREDPREFS\""
        buildConfigField "String", "STORED_HOST_URL_KEY", "\"com.northghost.afvclient.STORED_HOST_KEY\""
        buildConfigField "String", "STORED_CARRIER_ID_KEY", "\"com.northghost.afvclient.CARRIER_ID_KEY\""
        signingConfig signingConfigs.sining

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:sdk:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:openvpn:2.0.4'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.5.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.5.0.0'
    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"


    implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'

    //Preference Library
    implementation 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.9.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha02'

}
```

**Project level build.gradle File is here**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
            credentials { username "48a9b4c06b5dabbc03328ddcdbb7dfd8fab253ae" }
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```